# How to add selectoption values to CRON Expression Dynamically from vf page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, ui

I have a controller as

```
public String CreateCronExpression(String Time, List<wrapper> daylist){
  map<string,Integer> mapofDayAndInt= new map<string,Integer>();
  mapofDayAndInt.put('Sunday',1);
  mapofDayAndInt.put('Monday',2);
  mapofDayAndInt.put('Tuesday',3);
  mapofDayAndInt.put('Wednesday',4);
  mapofDayAndInt.put('Thursday',5);
  mapofDayAndInt.put('Friday',6);
  mapofDayAndInt.put('Saturday',7);
  string ss='';
  string mm='';
  string hh='';
  string dayofWeek='';
  String CronExpression='';
  list<Integer> selecteddays = new list<Integer>();
  for(wrapper objwrap: daylist){
      If(objwrap.selected == true){
        selecteddays.add(mapofDayAndInt.get(objwrap.day));
   }
  }
  if (selecteddays.length()>0)
  {
   for(Integer int: selecteddays){
     dayofWeek=dayofWeek+','+int;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     dayofWeek='*';
  }


  CronExpression=ss+mm+hh+'*'+'*'+dayofWeek;
  return CronExpression;

 }

  public class wrapper
    {
        public String day{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public wrapper(String a)
        {
            day = a;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
```

My Client requirement is Schedule a batch class from visualforce dynamically like salesforce schedule apex UI

How to add Frequency as CRON Expresson Dynamically From visualforce page?

please help me..............

thnx!!!!!!

Comment: Are you trying to build a string to pass into [System.schedule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm)?

Comment: ya we can say that string

Comment: and where is the VF page that is giving you the issue?